# How do I optimize build of custom mode in vue cli 3

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-3

We can set custom modes in cli 3.

Because it is not a production mode, it would not be a optimized build.

How do I set config to custom mode to reach the optimized build as production mode.

[custom mode(staging) in package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQvbb.png)

[The files of default production mode(optimized), command: npm run build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu8xI.png)

[The files of custom mode(staging) (not optimized), command: npm run staging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaRUl.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are Mixing between two things first `vue build app.vue` command builds a production ready bundle.

Modes are just another name for environment, which specifies if you’re in development, production or test mode.

if you want to associate different mode with your build you can append it like that `vue-cli-service build --mode development`. by --mode you assign what environment variables you need with that build.

if you want the stage build to be optimized as production just put NODE_ENV=production in the start of your .env.staging file .

ref: CLI docs [modes and env in cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode)

Comment: [Abaner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9823362/abner-wang) did that make any sense to you if so can you please accept the answer and Upvote it

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the key point is the results between default production mode and custom mode, I would edit my question to show the differences.

Comment: Dear don't know if you are still interested i found the solution is to put NODE_ENV=production in the start of your .env.staging file .
ref : https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode

Comment: @AhmedMagdy thanks for ```NODE_ENV=production```, it worked for me

Comment: @AbnerWang Hey I think I have answered your question can Accept the answer.